# My simple card game will not show the second card before it resets it's game board

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

My simple card game below will not show the picture of the second card **before** it goes on to display the alert message and then immediately reset its game board. Anyone able to help ?

Also, I'm kind of new to coding may anyone help to point out areas of code I could improve on?

```
var cards = ['queen', 'queen', 'king', 'king'];
var cardsInPlay = [];    
var gb = document.getElementById('game-board');

//allows me to compare the pushed elements in the array cardsInPlay and erase all innerHTML when its done
var isMatch = function () {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert('You found a match!');
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, try again.')
    };

    document.getElementsByClassName('card')[0].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('card')[1].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('card')[2].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('card')[3].innerHTML = "";
};
//pushes the 'data-card-' of a card upon an eventlistener and "flip"/show the cards image based on its 'data-card' info. triggers function check if cards are a match.
var isTwoCards = function () {
    cardsInPlay.push(this.getAttribute('data-card'));

    if (this.getAttribute('data-card') === 'king') {
        this.innerHTML = '<img src="kingcard.png" alt="King" />'
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = '<img src="queencard.png" alt="Queen" />'
    };

    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        isMatch(cardsInPlay);
        cardsInPlay = [];
    };
};
//iterates and creates cards, while setting an attribute and eventListener
var createCards = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var children = document.createElement('div');    

        children.className = 'card';

        gb.appendChild(children);

        document.getElementsByClassName('card')[i].setAttribute('data-card', cards[i]);
        document.getElementsByClassName('card')[i].addEventListener('click', isTwoCards);           
    };
};

createCards();
```

Comment: New to programming? Start by commenting your code. Your var/func names are good, but you should comment functional blocks so others can see not just what it does, but what it is SUPPOSED to do.

Comment: Please post the html document also. Only **isMatch** is having alert and it doesn't update any DOM

Comment: Also, please refer to this article for instructions on how to provide a working example: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: As a suggestion, perhaps use a html element (eg. a styled `div`) to display your notice to the user about their match success rather than use the `alert` function. The element would work like a "modal" with a semi-transparent background that would allow the user to "see through" to the cards selected. The modal would have a button that when clicked, dismissed the message, and reset the game board. This way you're separating your match logic from your reset logic by waiting for the user to interact

Comment: Thankyou for looking at my code. i've added the comments for the functions. :) and i'm looking through snippets as well. :D. @haxxxton i will try to create that out !  ty ty